# Trouble filtering objects on basis of dates in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a Task model where every task has deadline.

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey('Users', related_name='user_assigned_to')
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
```

I need to filter out task that has deadline date earlier than today's date with other filters.So I used this query:

```
all_task = Tasks.objects.filter(Q(assigned_to = i),Q(deadline<datetime.datetime.today()),~Q(status="Done"))
```

But this give me error:

> NameError: name 'deadline' is not defined

If i changed the query to(just changing < sign to = ) :

```
all_task = Tasks.objects.filter(Q(assigned_to = i),Q(deadline=datetime.datetime.today()),~Q(status="Done"))
```

The above query returns me objects , but why it is not returning objects in case I use < or > with datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because using `<` is trying to use it as a name instead of a keyword argument.

```
..., Q(deadline__lt=datetime.datetime.today()), ....
```

["Field lookups"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Comment: How would we do "less than equal to" rather than just "less than" in same case?

Comment: When one has been given a link, it would behoove one to *take a fricking look*...

Answer (score 0):

have u try this one ??

```
all_task = Tasks.objects.filter(Q(assigned_to = i),Q(deadline__lt = datetime.datetime.today()),~Q(status="Done"))
```

I hope it will work.